# How to catch error 1062 "duplicate entry" independent from used database/engine?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In a project I started out with MySQL as database. Instead of checking first, I just do an insert and if I get an IntegrityError exception with code 1062, I know that there is a duplicate entry and warn the user, to do this and that.

that looks basically like this:

```
try:
    # add duplicate, nothing bad happens yet, is only in sqla session
    db.session.add(User(email='already_used_email@address_that_has_to_be_unique.com'))
    # commit, now the IntegrityError is raised, when sqla inserts
    db.session.commit()
except IntegrityError as e:
    db.session.rollback()
    # this is what i do with mysql, check the exception for code 1062
    # how can i replace this with something db independent?
    code, msg = e.orig
    if code == 1062:
        # send warning
        pass
```

Now, for one this makes it already impossible to test with eg. in-memory sqlite. Not nice, but I could live with that.

Second however, I might (have to/want to for other out of scope of this question issues) switch to Postgres. Of course I could just change the code to (also) check for Postgres error codes, but I was hoping there is a way to have SQLALchemy tell me, that a duplicate happened independent from the database. A database dialect abstraction...?

Comment: IMHO, you don't need to rollback after a failed commit. You'll have to fetch the error code _before_ the rollback; it would otherwise probably get "no current transaction to rollback" or the like.

Comment: I recall, that when I did not do a rollback, the database complained about an unclear state of the session (or was it sqlalchemy complaining, i am not sure). Anyway, I do catch the error before the rollback! The IntegrityError is raised by the commit, when i inserted a duplicate before. I'll update the sample, to show the insert.

Comment: Could be that the state is undifined. In that case you'll indeed have to first get the error-state, than reset the state with a rollback, and maybe catch the resulting error from that operation, too.

Comment: you may need to use `e.orig.args` rather than `e.orig`  to unpack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to search for is something called "SQLSTATE" - a set of standard error codes that cover most common RDBMS error states. They don't necessarily provide enough detail for all purposes though, and I don't know if sqlite supports them.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-handling.html

Comment: Thanks, SQLSTATE was a good tip. Several MySQL codes map to the same SQLSTATE code though, 23000 in my case. SQLite has a SQLITE_CONSTRAINT code (http://sqlite.org/capi3ref.html).

I'll look into how to get those codes via SQLAlchemy exceptions, and accept the answer as soon I have it all figured out. Completely backend-agnostic error handling does not seem possible, but at least I have an educated guess, what's going on.

Comment: As Michael Bayer writes (http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03039.html) getting the SQLSTATE via exceptions is not in the scope of sqlalchemy, but the underlying db library. It seems MySQLdb does not deliver, as `exc.orig` only contains `(1062, "Duplicate entry 'xxx' for key 'ix_yyy")`. I'll stick to Michael's recommendation to just catch `IntegrityError` and forward the original error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `pymysql`, then you can do this.

```
except pymysql.err.IntegrityError:
        db_connection.rollback() # rollback
        return jsonify({"message":"DUPLICATE"}), 400 # just json return
```

and this link is pymysql.err's github code.
You can find `other exception` from here!
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/main/pymysql/err.py